# How do I know if IP Multicasting is enabled on my network?

Tags: linux, redhat

Is there a way to know if the Red Hat Linux Servers on my network have IP Multicasting enabled?
The output that I get by running the cat /proc/net/igmp command is the following

```
Idx Device    : Count Querier   Group    Users Timer    Reporter
1   lo        :     0      V3
                010000E0     1 0:00000000       0
2   eth0      :     3      V3
                010000E0     1 0:00000000       0
```

1. Does this mean that IP Multicasting
   is enabled on my network?
2. Does this also mean that th server from which I ran the cat command belongs to Group 1?

Comment: try below link may help http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO.html http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-2482 http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-8706

Comment: This example worked for me. And help me understand how this works https://github.com/bjornl/ipv6_multicast_example

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To check if multicast is enabled on the interface do a "ifconfig eth0" and look for: MULTICAST

Comment: ifconfig command is not enabled on the servers on our network.

Comment: On RedHat-flavour systems normal users don't have `/sbin` (where `ifconfig` lives) in their path. If you're on a RedHat-like system and not the `root` user try running it as `/sbin/ifconfig`.

Comment: Thanks Mark,
Running ifconfig from sbin gives me the following output

`eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:22:1A:AF:DB  
          inet addr:10.1.0.74  Bcast:10.1.7.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::214:22ff:fe1a:afdb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:70747195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6965432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100`
I can see MULTICAST in the output.

Comment: Your eth0 interface has multicast enabled :)

Comment: "netstat -g" will give you group membership information.

Comment: This will say if the interface supports (actually: if it has it enabled) multicast (which almost all of them do), not if the network supports it.

Answer (score 6):

According to [howto](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO.html#s3)

```
cat /proc/net/igmp
```

will show the groups you are currently subscribed to

Comment: how can I subscribe to other groups or interfaces?? which I got from netstat -g

Answer (score 0):

[These days](https://www.linux.com/learn/replacing-ifconfig-ip), [iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2), or rather its `ip` command will also give you the answer:

```
$ ip link
```

(or `ip l` for short)

will present you with something like this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 [...]
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 [...]
    link/ether ab:cd:ef:12:34:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

where you can see that there is no multicast on my loopback device, but yes, my ethernet port does indeed do multicast.