# How do I know if IP Multicasting is enabled on my network in Windows?

Tags: windows, multicast

[How do I know if IP Multicasting is enabled on my network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/137976/how-do-i-know-if-ip-multicasting-is-enabled-on-my-network)

It is same question as above but for windows.

Answer (score 17):

from a command line:

```
netsh interface ip show joins
```

Displays IP multicast groups that have been joined on one or more interfaces. If an interface is not specified, multicast groups for all interfaces are shown.

Comment: a 'route print' would also show you network destination in the routing table for multicast.