# individual windows machine refuses to join multicast group on any network interface

Tags: networking, multicast

I have written a piece of software which joins a multicast group and processes packets. This seems to work on a number of machines I've tested with, both with Windows (tested on XP through to 8.1) and linux. Except for one machine: a laptop with Windows 8.1.

I had a look at the question [How do I know if IP Multicasting is enabled on my network in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/262634/how-do-i-know-if-ip-multicasting-is-enabled-on-my-network-in-windows) and from that tried running `netsh interface ip show joins`, only to confirm that this machine does not join the multicast group on any of the network interfaces (wifi or ethernet) I try my software out on. I have looked out for IGMP messages on wireshark, too, but can't see any. I have disabled firewalls, etc. but still nothing.

I have tried my software on another windows machine and it works without issues (without having to touch firewalls) and I see the correct group joined when I run `netsh interface ip show joins`.

The only variable I can see with this particular machine is that it is a laptop. Is there a particular setting I need to enable in windows to allow laptops to receive multicast packets? Is there another way I can debug this issue. It's driving me up the wall!

Thanks.

Further note: I have tried running the software in a Linux VM. Under the host (Windows) OS, the Bridge interface shows it joining a multicast group in `netsh interface ip show joins`. But the hardware interface still has no joins. And no packets are received.

Comment: Oh interesting. I just noticed that when I run the software in windows, it always binds to the VirtualBox network bridge. if I disable the VirtualBox network bridge, the ```netsh interface ip show joins``` shows joins on the correct interface. This is promising... but I do really need that VirtualBox interface. Calling a SetBindIP() style function in my code isn't forcing it to bind to the correct interface.

Comment: I've had a look at the routing tables through route print and saw that the route for 224.0.0.0 on the VirtualBox bridge had a lower cost metric than the one on the ethernet card. So the OS must be overriding the preference I set in software. I removed all multicast routes(!!) in the routing table through ```route delete 224.0.0.0```, then called ```route add 224.0.0.0 mask 240.0.0.0 <ip of correct interface> metric 200```. Amazingly, this now causes no joins listed on any interface.