# how to find the number of members in a Windows IP multicast

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, multicast

I am able to find multicast groups by using this in Command Prompt (I found this at serverfault [How do I know if IP Multicasting is enabled on my network in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/262634/how-do-i-know-if-ip-multicasting-is-enabled-on-my-network-in-windows)).

```
netsh interface ip show joins
```

Here is the result:

```
Scope       References  Last  Address
----------  ----------  ----  ---------------------------------
0                    0  Yes   213.0.0.1
0                    1  Yes   213.0.0.23
```

I am able to use 213.0.0.23 for the multicast IP address to send/receive data. My question is how I can find the number of members in a multicast group?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to use IGMP to discover which hosts are subscribed to multicast groups. By the way, `213.0.0.23` is not a valid multicast address. You send from a regular IP address to a multicast address. The multicast address  range is `224.0.0.0/4`, but some addresses are  reserved for special purposes (e.g. `224.0.0.1` is the all-hosts multicast group). In general, you should use multicast groups in the administratively scoped range (`239.0.0.0/8`).

Comment: Ron, 213.0.0.23 is what I made up to protect our system.  I have a few Windows virtual servers (2012 R2 Standard). Do you have a pointer for install/configure IGMP on servers?

Comment: You don't need to make up multicast group numbers since they cannot be routed on the Internet. All hosts have IGMP enabled. You should learn how IGMP works: [RFC 3376](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3376) and [RFC 4605](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3376). There may be tools to help with this, but "_product, service, or learning material recommendations_" are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Ron. Our servers run on the same internal network (not on the internet). We use multicast for Tomcat clustering. Is multicast a good solution in our case? Thanks for your info. Voted up your answers.

Comment: I can't answer that question. I plead application ignorance; I'm a network guy.